# ag-grid error refused to load font causing css breaking issue

Tags: ag-grid

I am getting this error while using ag-grid in production Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABAAAAABkcAAsAAAAANDgAABjKAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHIkuBmAAi2IKwkC1WQE2AiQDgjgLgR4ABCAFhEYHhSwbbCxFRoaNA5AAd3UjKjipERWchuz/OsEcw5oG2b/YSMJ1vzTP0uIUhDB6moOzW4Im6BqI0CXBRVkyL/LeDfcz+XvKIUlo8vDfful9M383SMYAlgLAqg4QfYVjiUKikBGqp7pVbPPXXPhvA5fwAWOyu+EjmqkEQlVVIatEjaiib9Qfwjn/r806tKTlgpUxpBIoeJngVVwnhk0Qnxi2dMyEOUxZO9N05jR7TOG9JROjEwO+wLP5fsuETRV2q0jkVATJmW7V+ZlpfaZ1YBair7eCRERaTxz5PxAMr3TwYfQb905f/5IzBzYKs38SGJbdtbl8Oukrke/0pNNfCBWgElgCS1AjgGDL/Q3T6CAlVIJPUP7zx1...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' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I am unable to reproduce this issue in the local.

Can anyone help me on this i want to know why this is happening and what is the solution for this.